# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found & flutter_ios-2.5.0/ios/Classes/GoogleMapPolygonController.h:5:8

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, google-maps

I updated packages and project. Then tried to run it, but i get:

> Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found
> /Users/altynbek/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_maps_flutter_ios-2.5.0/ios/Classes/GoogleMapPolygonController.h:5:8

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

i tried:

```
cd ios
pod update
cd ..
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

also tried to delete podfile.lock, to delete the   google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.8
and add again by terminal. but it's not working. i've tried flutter pub cache repair. but nothing works.